# Windows are disappearing and I don't know how, why and how to reverse it

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, firefox, desktop-icons

Basically, sometimes, with no warning or anything, the windows I have open disappear, but not close. For example, if I have music on a browser and that window disappears, the music still plays.

The thing is the window also disappears from the bar up top, so I can't click it from there. I was on Mozilla earlier (it had like 5 tabs open) and the window vanished. Then I opened Mozilla again and closed the browser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, it showed me the warning of closing 2 windows with, like, 6 tabs.

I don't know if I'm pressing something that's triggering this, if a process dies without an error and makes this happen or what, but I could use the help. Lastly, I have Xubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are accidentality switching to a different workspace (desktop). It's easily done in Xfce by simply scrolling the mouse wheel while the mouse is over the workspace switcher. You can find the workspace switcher on the top bar near to the right.

The mouse wheel shortcut can also be disabled by right-clicking the workspace switcher then `Properties` > uncheck `Switch workspaces using the mouse wheel`.

Comment: You were correct, although changing workspaces with the scroll button was possible anywhere in the desktop, since I don't have a workspace switcher.

Also, there wasn't a Properties tab in the switcher, so I just deleted all other workspaces to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

To reset or move a window position via the terminal in Ubuntu, you can use the wmctrl tool.

something like :

```
wmctrl -r <window_name> -e 0,100,100,-1,-1
```

should work